# Combining JSON data and converting to array using underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have the following JSON data:

```
    {
    "scan_stats": {
        "med_compl_clin": [
            {
                "clin": "Miller RPH, Susan S",
                "pct": "98"
            },
            {
                "clin": "Rollins RN, Beth L",
                "pct": "67"
            },
            {
                "clin": "Jenkins, Coney RUTH",
                "pct": "85"
            },
            {
                "clin": "Moore RPH, Kenneth W",
                "pct": "33"
            },
            {
                "clin": "Isaacs RPH, Daniel",
                "pct": "100"
            }
        ],
        "pt_compl_clin": [
            {
                "clin": "Miller RPH, Susan S",
                "pct": "34"
            },
            {
                "clin": "Rollins RN, Beth L",
                "pct": "88"
            },
            {
                "clin": "Wright , James ANTHONY",
                "pct": "90"
            },
            {
                "clin": "Jenkins, Coney RUTH",
                "pct": "75"
            },
            {
                "clin": "Moore RPH, Kenneth W",
                "pct": "58"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can change the above object into an array that has the all the pct (percentages) for each clin (clinician) once in an array. I want the clinicians that are not in both the med_compl_clin and the pt_compl_clin objects to have null in the array position for the object that particular clinician doesn't appear in:

```
[
  ["Miller RPH, Susan S", 98, 34],
  ["Rollins RN, Beth L", 67, 88],
  ["Wright , James ANTHONY", null, 90]
]  ... to the end of all clinicians
```

I am trying to use underscore.js to do it but can't get it right.

Comment: Try to `map` over the first array and `find` the respective `pct` value by comparing the `clin` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use just javascript.

Store json in a variable

```
var json = {
    "scan_stats": {
        "med_compl_clin": [...],
        "pt_compl_clin": [...]
    }
}
```

And then try this code:

```
var newObject = {};
for( people in json.scan_stats.med_compl_clin ){
    newObject[ json.scan_stats.med_compl_clin[people].clin] = { med_ptc : json.scan_stats.med_compl_clin[people].pct };
}
for( people in json.scan_stats.pt_compl_clin ){
    if( !newObject[ json.scan_stats.pt_compl_clin[people].clin ] )
        newObject[json.scan_stats.pt_compl_clin[people].clin] = {};

    newObject[json.scan_stats.pt_compl_clin[people].clin].pt_ptc = json.scan_stats.pt_compl_clin[people].pct;
}

var json = [];
for( people in newObject ){
    var med = null;
    var pt = null;

    if( newObject[people].med_ptc ) med = parseInt(newObject[people].med_ptc);
    if( newObject[people].pt_ptc ) pt = parseInt(newObject[people].pt_ptc);

    json.push( [ people, med, pt ] );
}
```

Now variable "json" holds your 2d array.